# how can I pass a swift array by reference between viewControllers in prepare(for segue:?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, pass-by-reference

I know that swift array structs are copied by value and not reference.  Is there a simple way that I can cast or otherwise pass the array by reference in my prepare(for segue:... method so that I may pass a reference to the array from viewController A to viewController B?

I have seen some answers that refer to passing an array to a function but I simply want to pass it to other viewControllers

Comment: You could use NSArray...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create wrapper class for your array and then pass that class reference wherever you want:

```
class ArrayWrapper {
    let array: [YourType]

    init(array: [YourType]) {
        self.array = array
    }
}
```

Comment: probably best to change to var array: [YourType] as I guess most often the passed array will need to be mutated.  but thanks for your answer.  it's what I was looking for.  Also good to note that multiple arrays can be held in this wrapper class if necessary.  thx.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve it by passing the values from  viewController A to viewController B. All you need to do is, take an array (arrB) in ViewController B .

```
let VB = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewControllerB") as! viewControllerB
vc.arrA = arrA
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

This will not pass reference but the values of area to arrB.

Answer (score 0):

If u want to transfer array from one controller to another controller using segue create array in your first controller like this

```
 var dataSource : [ANY MODEL CLASS] = []
```

use this method to transfer your data using segue

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "YOURSEGUE") {
            let vc = segue.destination as! YOUCONTROLLER
             vc.myArray = self.dataSource
        }
```

in your second controller create same type array

```
  var myArray : [ANY MODEL CLASS] = []
```

so now when you moved to another controller using this "YOURSEGUE" segue your array will have data

Answer (score 0):

create a global array like this

```
var myGlobalArray = [Int]()
class viewControllerA : UIViewController {

}
```

now you can use it everywhere. but this is not a good thing

Answer (score 0):

If you cast the array into NSArray it should do the work.